# What is the plural of status quo?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, irregular-plurals

A quick search suggests that *status quos* is most common pluralization of *status quo*. This form, however, is deeply unsatisfying. Clearly, *status* is the noun in this phrase, while *quo* is some sort of adverb or something. *Statuses quo* seems to me the most natural attempt to pluralize (but perhaps a different form of *quo* is necessary; I am not a Latin expert). Which plural form(s) are correct? Can I use *statuses quo*?

Comment: No, *statuses quo* is deeply unsatisfying. You must say *statī quo*.

Comment: @DanBron Are you sure? I thought I'd use the standard English plural of *status*, but if we are to go with Latin, then [this page](http://katherinebarber.blogspot.com/2011/09/status-quo.html) claims the plural of *status* is *status*.

Comment: I was making a joke. The point was very much that in English we pluralize fixed phrases, especially foreign phrases, as though the phrase were an indivisible unit: a single word. Feeling "deeply unsatisfied" at this state of affairs and trying to analyze the components of such phrases quickly leads us to absurd places (like those jokers who insist the plural of *octopus* is *octopi* and such). And what "the plural" of *status* is in Latin depends on gender, declension, etc.

Comment: @DanBron Good point -- as you can see, I am not a Latin expert :)

Comment: @Dan: status has only one gender (it's a masculine noun), and in English we generally use the nominative for Latin plurals, so the [Latin plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status) of status is statūs.  Since neither English nor Latin usually used the long vowel mark in writing, the written plural would be *status*. This was probably actually used in English back in the days when all educated people had been taught Latin.

Comment: @PeterShor To analyze the joke kinda misses the point, but ... the idea was quite specifically to *ignore* "[what we do in English](http://imgur.com/Qktj8aj)". Because it's deeply unsatisfying, of course.

Comment: Google Books claims 239 instances of ["stati quo"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stati+quo%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But quite a few of those are actually *Italian* texts, plus there are about five times as many instances of ["status quos"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22status+quos%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So I know which one I'd go for, standard Latin morphology notwithstanding.

Comment: I don't see what the plural could mean.  What is the plural of  the *idea* "the state of things"?

Comment: @Tim: It might seem an odd concept without context, but if you follow the links I just posted, I'm sure you'll agree that at least *some* instances are perfectly natural phrasing.

Comment: I find 'status quos' quite acceptable if not deeply satisfying. Certainly better than other suggestions here. Would you object to 'Confetti is often thrown as the newlyweds emerge from the building' on historic grounds? 'Have-nots' on morphological grounds?

Comment: @PeterShor I know at least one person (Brit, aged mid-60s or so) who uses _status_ as the plural of _status_ in all contexts.

Comment: @Janus: I think in one of my answers on this site I argued that *apparatus* is often treated as a semi-uncountable noun (an apparatus; two pieces of apparatus) because back when more people knew Latin, people weren't sure whether to use *apparatus* or *apparatuses* as the plural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ... and some of them are incorrect machine transliterations of [*in statu quo*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=statu+quo%2C+in+statu+quo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstatu%20quo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20statu%20quo%3B%2Cc0), where the Latin noun is in the ablative.

Comment: @Peter: Well, unlike OP I *don't* find the regular Anglicized form "deeply unsatisfying". And I only studied Latin for a few weeks when I was about 13, so I have no particular knowledge of (or affection for) the morphology of the dead language. I'd rather stick with the standard pluralization rule whenever there's at least a *reasonable* level of support from others. *Formulas, corpuses*, and *status quos* are all fine by me, even if "better educated" people turn their noses up at my "ignorance".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree; for me all this discussion has just confirmed that *status quos* is the best plural.  I suppose if you ***really*** want to appear erudite—or demented—you could use the Latin ablative plural of *statibus quo*, but Google only finds that form in Latin documents.

Comment: @Peter: Your "I agree" there prompted me to check the corpuses for ***formulas*** vs ***formulae*** in NGrams, and discover that [AmE has long favoured the "regular" form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulas%2Cformulae&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformulas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulae%3B%2Cc0) but [BrE has only just caught up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulas%2Cformulae&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformulas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulae%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: (But I might be a bit out on a limb with [***corpuses**!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corpora%2Ccorpuses&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorpora%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorpuses%3B%2Cc0) :)

Comment: @PeterShor Don't you mean "statibus quibus?" You forgot to make the pronoun plural.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth:  How about **haven'ts**? **havers-not**? **have-snot**?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Ngram chart for the years 1900–2008 tracking "status quos" (blue line) versus "stati quo" (nonvisible red line) versus "statibus quibus" (nonvisible green line) versus "statuses quo" (nonvisible yellow line):

[image]

The red line, the green line, and the yellow line aren't visible because the matches for those terms are too few to register against the frequency of "status quos." At least until very recently, "status quos" was virtually the only plural form of "status quo" in use in English. I say "until recently" because of the fourteen verifiable Google Books matches for "stati quo" since 1943 (when the oldest match appears), seven are from the years 2000–2013; and of the fifteen matches for "statuses quo" since 1968 (the oldest), ten are from the years 1998–2015. So those two forms may be improving on their past very low level of popularity, though not by leaps and bounds. In contrast, *statibus quibus* appears in just two Google Books matches of English texts, one from 1836 and one from 1959.

A Google Books search finds matches for "status quos" going back to 1909. From William Bates, "[The Japanese Our Coming Merchants and Carriers: The Apparent Intention of the "Status Quo" Agreement with Japan](https://books.google.com/books?id=dWTUAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22status+quos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMIj5_ApNfDxwIVwqSICh0WZAsq#v=onepage&q=%22status%20quos%22&f=false)" (1909):

> No President can validate it ["a suspension of trade regulations, made in pursuance of a compact for 'navigation laws'"] in favor of any foreign country; and Congress should immediately repeal it, and terminate all conventions under it. The country looks to CONGRESS to step into the arena and put an end to bartering away our shipping trade, with its invaluable national advantages, for "open doors," "**status quos**," or other illusive oriental benefits of limited usefulness.

There have been many instances of "status quos" in the years that followed, including 55 in the period 2006–2008 alone.

From these results it seems evident that most of the people publishing in English who are willing to hazard a plural form of "status quo" in print have adopted "status quos" as their choice, although some few have adopted "stati quo," presumably as a back formation from "status quo" via what they take to be the normal rules for creating plural forms of Latin words whose singular form ends in -*us*; and some few others have opted for "statuses quo," presumably on the model of "attorneys general" and "Eggs McMuffin."

**Note:** I didn't try to identify and count instances in which "status quo" was used as a plural form of "status quo," as discussed in comments above by Peter Shor and Janus Bahs Jacquet. I can't think of any way to separate the plural forms from the singular forms that doesn't involve examining each match for "status quo" individually, which I am not willing to do.

Comment: I can't decide which is the nonvisible red line and which ...

Answer (score 0):

I needed a context.  I looked at the first link provided by FumbleFingers and found this:

> The HPS should consider the existing stati quo of the organisations
>   involved (and interested) in harbour protection.

I would like it better like this:

> The HPS should consider the existing status quo of the organisations
>   involved

Comment: "stati quo" is just terrible...

Comment: For this meaning [Latin plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status#Etymology_2_2) of *status* is *status*. The plural *stati* applies to a [different meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status#Etymology_1) of *status*.

Answer (score 0):

While a good question, I think none of the answers here provide an adequate answer.

'Status quo' does not describe an object that would be calculable. The closest translation of the term is "the existing state of affairs", or -- by simplification -- "the way things are". There is no meaningful way to pluralize the context or the meaning of this phrase, in the same way that you cannot pluralize "the existing state of affairs" or "the existing balance of relations", and so forth. Now, the status quo, however, can also be construed as either a logic or a 'state' as such. So, if you refer to politics that produce or re-produce forms of status quo, then you can say this: 'forms' of status quo. You can refer to 'status quo states' -- which while kind of redundant uses the word 'states' with a different connotation to that implied by the translation of status quo itself. A status quo state is a state in which a status quo emerges. A system of continuous change, to highlight an example, would be unable to be defined as any kind of 'status quo'. Similarly, you can refer to the logic of the status quo -- not exactly a plural form but one which can allow you to provide more nuance to your argumentation.

These concepts are explored in more detail in post-anarchism. There is generally no consistent discourse to discuss such phenomena, but 'non-hegemony' could be a good term to look up. Deleuze and Guattari also reflect on this phenomenon and have provided an account of what a logic that does not result in a status quo could be like.